# Allow guest profile to update opportunity line Item

Tags: apex, query, rest-service, restresource, queryexception

I am trying to setup a web hook to use along side PandaDoc to update opportunity line items once approved but the query on web hook when ran on a guest profile does not return a line item. I can run it fine in the WorkBench. My code is below

```
/**
 * Created by zachary on 12/20/20.
 */
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/pandadocwebhook')
global with sharing class pandadocWebHook {
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(){
        String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        body = body.substring(1, body.length() - 1).replace('\"salesforce.opportunity_id\"', '\"oppId\"');
        JSONParse json = new JSONParse(body);
        String jobId = json.get('data.metadata.oppId').getStringValue();
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItemsToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
        for(JSONParse product : json.get('data.products').asList()) {
            Boolean approved = product.get('options.optional_selected').getBooleanValue();
            if(approved){
                String productName = product.get('name').getStringValue();
                Decimal productPrice = product.get('price').getDecimalValue();
                OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem = [SELECT Id, Acceptance__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = :jobId AND Name = :productName AND UnitPrice = :productPrice LIMIT 1];
                oppLineItem.Acceptance__c = true;
                opportunityLineItemsToUpdate.add(oppLineItem);
            }
        }
        update opportunityLineItemsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

The response when ran from Postman is

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject\n\nClass.pandadocWebHook.doPost: line 18, column 1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Word of caution** on this, after Spring 21 guest users won't have the access to edit, delete, view all, and modify all access on any object.

Check the pre-release notes [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_crud_perms_removed.htm&release=230&type=5).

Hence the code you have will not work even if you manage to get it working now!!!

**Better Solutions**

Move away from Guest users and build a Middleware on Heroku or any other platform that can securely authenticate to the salesforce to get this type of functionality working.

**Workaround**

This has security implications and you might want to be very careful before adopting and explain stake holders implications of running code in the system context.

Go **without sharing** in Apex as below

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/pandadocwebhook')
global without sharing class pandadocWebHook {
 @HttpPost
  global static void doPost(){
    String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    body = body.substring(1, body.length() - 1).replace('\"salesforce.opportunity_id\"', '\"oppId\"');
    JSONParse json = new JSONParse(body);
    String jobId = json.get('data.metadata.oppId').getStringValue();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItemsToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(JSONParse product : json.get('data.products').asList()) {
        Boolean approved = product.get('options.optional_selected').getBooleanValue();
        if(approved){
            String productName = product.get('name').getStringValue();
            Decimal productPrice = product.get('price').getDecimalValue();
            OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem = [SELECT Id, Acceptance__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = :jobId AND Name = :productName AND UnitPrice = :productPrice LIMIT 1];
            oppLineItem.Acceptance__c = true;
            opportunityLineItemsToUpdate.add(oppLineItem);
        }
     }
     update opportunityLineItemsToUpdate;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. We will move it to rails on heroku.

Comment: i am sure our twilio incoming message service 'll be broke. thanks for workaround